# Google Docs. Excel. Перенос из одной таблицы в другую, по цвету ячейки

Tags: excel, google-docs

Есть таблица, в которой в первой колонке находятся название региона.
Ячейки с регионами залиты (закрашены) разными цветами (зеленый и красный).

Как мне из этой таблицы, перенести в разные таблицы (на разных листах), в зависимости от цвета заливки ячейки с регионами, полностью информацию о регионе (остальные столбцы таблицы в этой строке региона, т.е диапазон ячеек)?

Все дело происходит в Google Docs, т.е в облачной, онлайн эксельке

Ответ формулой - приветствуется)

Comment: GOGLE-таблицы и Excel не одно и то же.  И макросы  VBA в Google не работают.  Там на JS пишут

Comment: Добавил изменения в вопрос.

Comment: А покажите пожалуйста как вы пробовали и что там у вас не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько мне известно прямой формулы для определения цвета ячейки нет.
Я бы сделал VBA функцию:

```
Function IsCellColor(curCell As Range, compColorIndex As Integer)
    If curCell.Interior.ColorIndex = compColorIndex Then IsCellColor = True Else IsCellColor = False1
End Function
```

И потом бы по ее возвращаемому значению определял бы желаемое.
`ColorIndex` можно узнать с помощью (в документации не нашел сходу, а долго искать было, честно, лень):

```
Function GetCellColor(curCell As Range) As Variant
  GetCellColor = curCell.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

В моем случае зеленый = 14, красный = 3.
Применение в ячейке назначения:

```
=ЕСЛИ(IsCellColor(B3;14);"Зеленый";"")
```

Костыль, конечно, но другого пока в голову не приходит.
Кроме того, макросы не пересчитываются автоматически, поэтому надо обновлять лист по Ctrl+Shift+F9. 
Проверено в Office 365 Pro Plus со всем обновлениями.

p.s. Мда, к своему стыду пропустил мимо ушей про Google Docs... Оставлю решение на всякий случай, вдруг кому пригодится.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, буду еще варианты рассматривать, т.к не очень понимаю таксходу что такое VBA

Comment: @I.Simonov VBA - это Visual Basic for Applications (подробнее [тут](http://www.askit.ru/custom/vba_office/m1/01_02_basis_vba.htm), например)

Answer (score 1):

Так как есть метка `Excel`, возможно, кому-то пригодится еще одно решение с помощью VBA.

Макрос по первому столбцу сам определяет принадлежность строки к цветовому диапазону и разносит данные разных цветовых диапазонов по отдельным листам. Количество цветов неограничено (вернее, ограничено только параметрами *Excel* и объемом оперативной памяти)

```
Sub ColorCroup()
    Dim aData(), aTemp()
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim lColor As Long
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long, j As Long
    Const lClmn As Byte = 5 ' к-во столбцов'

    With Worksheets("цвет")
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        aData = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(i, lClmn).Value ' даные в массив'
        Set rRng = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(i, 1) ' переменной присваиваем диапазон столбца А'
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ReDim aTemp(1 To UBound(aData), 1 To lClmn)

    For j = 1 To lClmn
        aTemp(1, j) = aData(1, j) ' в массив выгрузки записываем шапку таблицы'
    Next j

    For i = 2 To UBound(aData)
        k = 1

        If aData(i, 1) <> "not" Then
            lColor = rRng(i, 1).Interior.Color ' числовое значение заливки ячейки'

            For n = i To UBound(aData)
                If rRng(n, 1).Interior.Color = lColor Then ' при совпадении цвета'
                     k = k + 1

                     For j = 1 To lClmn
                        aTemp(k, j) = aData(n, j) ' заполняем массив выгрузки'
                     Next j

                     aData(n, 1) = "not" ' отметка об использовании строки'
                End If
            Next n
        End If

        If k > 1 Then Worksheets.Add.Cells(1, 1).Resize(k, lClmn).Value = aTemp ' создание и заполнение листа'
    Next i

    Set rRng = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub
```